# How to return multiple strings on different HTML elements in async /await?

Tags: javascript, async-await, fetch

I am trying to get the return results (title, content, poet) to show up on the HTML. Right now, only the content is changing dynamically whenever I refresh the page. I'm not sure what I am doing wrong in .then() - can you put multiple document.getElementId in there, or is there another way to structure it?

Note: I commented the other document.getElementId and document.getElementsByTagName because they just ended up showing the entire content 2 times

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <link rel = "stylesheet" href = "style.css">
    <title>Fetch a poem</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1 class = "title">Title</h1>
    <h3 id = "content">Fetch a Poem</h3>
    <p id = "poet">Poet</p>
    <script>
      console.log('about to fetch a poem');
      catchPoem()
        .then(poem => {
          // document.getElementsByClassName('title').innerText = poem;
          document.getElementById('content').innerText = poem;
          // document.getElementById('poet').innerText = poem;
          console.log('content is showing');
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.log('error!');
          console.error(error);
        });

      async function catchPoem() {
        const response = await fetch('https://www.poemist.com/api/v1/randompoems');
        let json = await response.json();
        let title = json[0].title
        let content = json[0].content
        let poet = json[0].poet.name
        console.log(title)
        console.log(content)
        console.log(poet)
        return [title, content, poet]
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your code is alright. If you check console you will see it gives CORS error. You can try some chrome extension for that or allow CORS from server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set all three in the `.then` block

```
document.querySelector( '.title' ).textContent = title;
document.getElementById( 'content' ).textContent = content;
document.getElementById( 'poet' ).textContent = poet;
```

I've used `textContent` here, You can use `innerText`

```js
console.log('about to fetch a poem');
catchPoem()
  .then(([title, content, poet]) => {
    // document.getElementsByClassName('title').innerText = poem;
    document.querySelector('.title').textContent = title;
    document.getElementById('content').textContent = content;
    document.getElementById('poet').textContent = poet;
    // document.getElementById('poet').innerText = poem;
    console.log('content is showing');
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.log('error!');
    console.error(error);
  });

async function catchPoem() {
  const response = await fetch('https://www.poemist.com/api/v1/randompoems');
  let json = await response.json();
  let title = json[0].title
  let content = json[0].content
  let poet = json[0].poet.name
  return [title, content, poet]
}
```

```css
h1, p{
  text-align: center;
}

h1, h3, p{
  padding: .5rem 1rem;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.title{
  background-color: cadetblue;
}

#content{
  background-color: chocolate;
}

#poet{
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="title">Title</h1>
<h3 id="content">Fetch a Poem</h3>
<p id="poet">Poet</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <link rel = "stylesheet" href = "style.css">
    <title>Fetch a poem</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1 id = "title">Title</h1>
    <h3 id = "content">Fetch a Poem</h3>
    <p id = "poet">Poet</p>
    <script>
      console.log('about to fetch a poem');
      catchPoem()
        .then(poem => {
          document.getElementById('title').innerText = poem[0];
          document.getElementById('content').innerText = poem[1];
          document.getElementById('poet').innerText = poem[2];
          console.log('content is showing');
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.log('error!');
          console.error(error);
        });

      async function catchPoem() {
        const response = await fetch('https://www.poemist.com/api/v1/randompoems');
        let json = await response.json();
        let title = json[0].title
        let content = json[0].content
        let poet = json[0].poet.name
        console.log(title)
        console.log(content)
        console.log(poet)
        return [title, content, poet]
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Another Way Of Generalization**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <title>Fetch a poem</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="content">
      <p id="loader">Loading Poems ....</p>
    </div>
    <script>
      console.log("about to fetch a poem");
      catchPoem()
        .then((poems) => {
          let div = document.getElementById("content");
          div.removeChild(document.getElementById("loader"));
          for (let poem of poems) {
            let title = document.createElement("h1");
            title.innerHTML = poem.title || "No Title";
            div.appendChild(title);

            let poemTag = document.createElement("h3");
            poemTag.innerHTML = poem.content || "No Poem";
            div.appendChild(poemTag);

            let poet = document.createElement("p");
            poet.innerHTML = poem.poet.name || "No Poet";
            div.appendChild(poet);
          }
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log("error!" + error);
        });

      async function catchPoem() {
        const response = await fetch("https://www.poemist.com/api/v1/randompoems");
        let json = await response.json();
        return json;
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Just as a note. For modern JavaScript you most of the time want to use `??` instead of `||` if you want to create default/fallback values.